# Angular 6 - receive HTTP GET request on app initialization

Tags: angular, http, server

When my Angular app is started for the first time, meaning right before the web application's pages are returned to the client's browser, I want to extract some information from the HTTP request that requested the app in the first place.

Specifically, I want to access the headers of the HTTP request that called the angular app, from inside the angular app.

Is there anyway to do this in Angular 6?

Thanks

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/router#resolve-pre-fetching-component-data

Comment: @R.Richards I might not have been clear, but I want to access the headers of the HTTP request that called the angular app, from inside the angular app.

Comment: Then update the question to make it clear!

Comment: @R.Richards I updated the question now. Do you know how I can do this?

Comment: This may help you do that: https://angular.io/guide/http#reading-the-full-response

Comment: @R.Richards I'm not trying to read an HTTP response, but rather read the HTTP request that the server that the angular app is on first receives before returning the Angular web pages back to the client's browser.

Comment: if I understand you correctly then what you is after it should be on the server side not on the client (Angular) side, right?

Comment: @robert The Angular app sits on a server, and when a user types in the URL for the app in his browser, the browser sends a GET request to the server that the angular app sits on to get all the web pages of the app. What I want to do is process that GET request *before* sending back the pages of the app to the user.

Comment: something like this: https://angular.io/guide/universal#filtering-request-urls

Comment: @robert Wonderful, I think that's it. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a service that intercept the request implements the HttpInterceptor interface, you can make a clone of the request and push what you want, and then return.

@Injectable()
export class RequestInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

```
constructor(private tokenService: TokenService) {}

intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpSentEvent 
    | HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse<any> | HttpUserEvent<any>> {

        if(this.tokenService.hasToken()) {
            const token = this.tokenService.getToken();
            req = req.clone({
                setHeaders: {
                    'x-access-token': token
                }
            });
        }
        return next.handle(req);
}
```

Don't forget to declare the service in a module:

providers: [{ provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, useClass: RequestInterceptor, multi: true }]

Comment: Sorry, but Angular interceptors only intercept *outgoing* requests that the angular app makes. I want to intercept requests that are coming to the server that the Angular app is on.

Comment: @Kingamere [Interceptors](https://angular.io/guide/http#intercepting-requests-and-responses) can be used for requests *and* responses. You should consider doing *some* research before posting a question.

Comment: @R.Richards That interceptor service intercepts requests going out from the angular app to some remote server, and responses from that remote server. I'm looking to intercept requests that the browser makes to the angular app itself. Something like this: angular.io/guide/universal#filtering-request-urls